# dynamic fetch query for different condition every time

Tags: php, mysql

**Fetch records on basis of new condition every time**

```
for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) { 
    $fe=mysqli_fetch_array($selq);
    $s="select * from module where main='".$fe[1]."'";
    print_r($s1=mysqli_query($db,$s));

}
while ($con=mysqli_fetch_array($s1))
{
  echo '<div class="span6 padbottom black"><h3 class="post-title">'.$con[2].'</h3>'.$con[3].'</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span5 padbottom dmright">
            <img class="padup" src="uploads/'.$con[4].'" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>';
}
```

i want to write a dynamic query to fetch new rows every other time .
my current code is as above and database is this

main module table

[image]

module table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May below code can help you out.

```
for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) { 
    $selq = mysqli_query($db, "your query");
    $fe=mysqli_fetch_array($selq);
    $s="select * from module where main='".$fe[1]."'";
    $s1=mysqli_query($db,$s)
    // print_r($s1=mysqli_query($db,$s));

    while ($con=mysqli_fetch_array($s1))
    {
        echo '<div class="span6 padbottom black"><h3 class="post-title">'.$con[2].'</h3>'.$con[3].'</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span5 padbottom dmright">
            <img class="padup" src="uploads/'.$con[4].'" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>';
    }
}
```

`mysqli_fetch_array` will fetche record each time and print them in `div`.  Comment if you have any queries. we will glad to help you out.

Comment: scenario is  I want to fetch all records from differect main_module name  and i want to make query dynamic that every time 
select * from main_module where " condition "
condition will b changed automatically via some dynamic code